# Debug --> How to simulate no flash player installed?

Tags: debugging, flash

Is there a way to simulate not having flash player installed, so I can see what users who visit a page without the plugin see my page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend downloading MS Virtual PC or VMWare Server (both free) and create a VM to test this functionality. Its the only way to be sure. Also gets you the flexibility to test a lot of browser versions.

Answer (score 3):

In Firefox , Tools -> Add-ons -> Plugins -> Shockwave flash -> Disable

Doesn't require you to restart the application. The name of the plugin can vary. It's how it's called in my Linux box.

Comment: This has helped me because disabling the plugin in Chrome just gives you a Chrome-generated message letting you know you've disabled Flash. This will actually just disable the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

IE - Disable the flash player plugin (Tools, Manage Add-ons)

Firefox - install the NoScript plugin

Chrome - install the FlashBlock extension

Other browsers, there's usually a way to temporarily disable any plugins you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

In chrome, inside the URL bar, write: chrome://settings.

In the new page, click on *disable* under the Flash plugin

Answer (score 0):

Get [Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/) and download the [IE Test environments](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en).